# Show a specific custom control on a form (and hide others)?

Tags: c#

I have a control named `myControl.cs`. It contains a groupbox and a button. In my `Form1.cs` when buttton is click `myControl` is created and put in a form `myControl.cs`. It can be created multiple times.

My question is when `myControl.cs` is click I want to show the button only to that specific `myControl.cs` and the other `myControl.cs` the button is hidden, how to achieve that?

myControl.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Erd_Maker
{
    public partial class myUserControl: UserControl
    {
        Label[] newColumnAdd;
        int ctr = 3;

        public myUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ini();
        }

        public void ini()
        {
            groupBox1.Click += new EventHandler(groupBox1_Click);
            newColumnAdd = new Label[99];
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 132);
        }

        public override bool AutoSize
        {
            get
            {
                return base.AutoSize;
            }
            set
            {
                base.AutoSize = value;
            }
        }

        public string tableNameText { get; set; }

        public string defaultColumnText { get; set; }

        private void table_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tableName.Text = tableNameText;
            defaultColumn.Text = defaultColumnText;
            groupBox1.Name = tableNameText;
        }

        private void groupBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GroupBox tbl = (GroupBox)sender;
            // This is the event I want to show a button for this control only
            // And the other buttons on the other control will be hidden

        }

    }
}
```

Form1.cs -> this is how I created myUserControl

```
             newTable[tableCounter] = new myUserControl();
             newTable[tableCounter].tableNameText = name;
             newTable[tableCounter].defaultColumnText = column;
             newTable[tableCounter].Name = name;
             newTable[tableCounter].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(tableCounter * 180, 1);
             this.databasePanel.Controls.Add(newTable[tableCounter]);
             newTable[tableCounter].Show();
```

I cannot post image see this .. [More explanation](https://erson-mi.s3.amazonaws.com/users_avatar/2014/12/01/10_6bce5e8f95_1.png)

Comment: use [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus(v=vs.110).aspx) events

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, sounds like you should store a list of buttons so you can hide them all at once, then unhide the one you want

Comment: see this .. https://erson-mi.s3.amazonaws.com/users_avatar/2014/12/01/10_6bce5e8f95_1.png

Comment: Your user control should have a Parent, over this parent you could iterate it's children, and exclude the child that matches the current user control (this), it should at least allow you to hide the items. Another option is to offer INotifyPropertyChanged to your usercontrol and upon ControlAdded / ControlRemoved events add/remove an eventhandler that would check any flags set on your usercontrol (and let the observer decide what to do with it)

Comment: Thanks @Icepickle I solved it and its close to the first option you give